# PayPal sandbox subscriptions error on payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate PayPal subscriptions into a project of mine and I've hit a snag. I managed to create a product and a plan and then redirect successfully to PayPal for approval but when I hit "Agree & Subscribe" I get the following error:

```
We're sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the funding source you've selected. Please try another funding source.
```

and there is a "Continue" button. I tried to pay using 2 different sandbox accounts that have payment sources set up but the error remains. One of the payment sources I have set up is "
The Bank Card Platinum Rewards" and as far as I know sandbox accounts come with pre-configured payment sources as was in this case.

I've, also, tried googling the error but I couldn't find exactly the same error though various other, similar, problems appear online.

I tried to go "Manage Automatic payments" and cancel all my previous subscriptions with the merchant but it didn't help.

I've looked [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Payments/Payment-Error-Sorry-we-couldn-t-set-up-your-subscription/td-p/1761727) and [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Payments/Unable-to-subscribe-to-a-service/td-p/1544708) but it doesn't seem there to be a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be due to corona lockdown

Comment: I doubt that is the case

Comment: Then create a ticket (and reply to both threads with the ticket# so future readers have a chance to see any outcome). Check what HTTP actually sends out in case PayPal's support really wants to understand your problem.

Comment: I found a way submit a ticket but it asks me to select a transaction first, though my problem is not with a transaction. Is there other way to submit a ticket?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Here more info: https://www.petarvasilev.com/problems-integrating-paypal/

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously a bug in the sandbox subscriptions. Just setup a fee in the plan and the bug will go away.